# How do I get the value of any Unicode character which is in character block NUMBER_FORMS?

Tags: unicode

[This wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Number_Forms) lists the "values" of all the code points which are in the Unicode character block "Number Forms".   This character block includes vulgar fractions but also roman numeral characters in addition to the ASCII digits.

I have found a solution for the vulgar fractions which involves normalizing them but is there a library which will just return me the value given *any* "Number Forms" Unicode code point?  I am looking for something more elegant than a simple code-point-to-float map.  Consider the following Java code:

```
public static float getValue(char theCharacter) {

    if (UnicodeBlock.of(theCharacter).equals(UnicodeBlock.NUMBER_FORMS)) {
        return getValueOfNumericFormCharacter(theCharacter);
    }
    return float.MIN_VALUE;
}
```

I am looking for something elegant which implements `getValueOfNumericFormCharacter(theCharacter)`.  Is there something out there?

Comment: A lot of unicode is table driven.  Why would this be different?  For example, your solution of normalizing is based on a very large unicode table (that happens to be built in)

Comment: Are you looking for [`Character.getNumericValue()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Character.html#getNumericValue\(int)\)?

Comment: @Max. I am looking for a solution for which the table is driven by the underlying unicode-block infrastructure.   I do not want to have to maintain my own table--especially job-to-job.  This kind of tablular information should be maintained by the standard owners and an API for it maintained by Java owners.

Comment: @Shawn.  I am not looking for `Character.getNumericValue()`  it does not return the same information.

Comment: It obviously doens't work for fractions, but does it not work for the roman numerals?